# GPU and mobo BIOS

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, power-supply, gpu

I have an older PC with the following specs:

- CPU: e7400 (C2D)
- GPU: 9600gt
- mobo: MSI p45 neo
- PSU: 550 W

My cousin gave me his old 8800GTX to replace my card. After connecting the two six pins and all the PC won't even post. The card was rarely used, then stored in its box until now (I don't think it is dead.) Furthermore my PSU is sufficient and I have no other peripherals running.

Do you think it may be GPU/ mobo BIOS (card launch late 2006, mobo 2008) that's causing this, and might it be worth an attempt to flash them? (Worth Noting: the PC does not seem to boot at all, when I push the power button it just shuts down instantly, not like when you have reached Windows.) The PCI-E slot is set for first priority and the old card still works.

Comment: it definitely sounds like your PSU isnt providing enough juice.  Have you tried the card in another computer?

Comment: Nope. . all my friends with suitable builds running ATI systems and don't wanna let me !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PSU is sufficient in **both** wattage AND 12v rail amperage. Particularly if your power supply is an older Antec. I recently fried an EVGA 660 Ti by not delivering it enough current. While my total wattage was 1200W with a the Antec NeoPower NeoLink 650+550, the amperage on the 12v rails was only 19 amps. The recommended minimum amperage on the EVGA page for the video card (which I sadly discovered after frying the card) was 24 amps.

In combination with a heavily overclocked i7 920 @ 4.35Ghz, my total power draw needed more amps than the power supply could provide. As you can imagine, I had quite a number of problems for the duration that video card was running in my system...random freezes, crashes, corrupted files, etc. ALL related to power.

I replaced my power supply with the EVGA SuperNOVA 1300W G2, which delivers 108amps on the 12v rail. Ever since, my system is not only running rock solid stable, I'm powering two 760 4Gb cards in SLI on top of that overclocked CPU and six sticks worth of 12Gb overclocked RAM.

I can't say whether your Neo PSU 550W is capable of supplying the necessary amperage or not, but it would be the first thing I check.